# How do I properly declare subdomains in Flask using Blueprint?

Tags: python, subdomain, flask

I have been following the methods provided in this post:
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167729/flask-subdomains-with-blueprint-getting-404

Here is my relevant code:

__init__.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="", static_folder="static"
import myApp.views
```

views.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, Blueprint
from myApp import app

app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'myapp.com'
app.url_map.default_subdomain = "www"

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "This is index page."

test = Blueprint('test', 'test', subdomain='test')

@test.route("/")
def testindex():
    return "This is test index page."

app.register_blueprint(test)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Using this method I am able to get subdomains 'test' and 'www' working, but now I am unable to access my website via IP address.

Any guidance into the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: If I were you I would declare my `SERVER_NAME` in an external config file and modify it accordingly. It supposes that you want to access you site either using ip either domain name. If you want both I think some htaccess magic might hide the thing to Flask.